# how to move left and right thumb of seek bar at a time in android

Tags: android, seekbar

Very good morning all of you.
I am new in android developing and i have one little query regarding the seek bar in android.
Actually i am developing one application in which i play video and and under the video i use custom seek bar with custom class. 
Now my question is that when i select video and its duration is assume 1 minute, But i want to set right thumb of seek bar at 15th second position every time.
And when i move left thumb of seek bar the right thumb must have to move automatically with it. And its mandatory to maintain seek bar with 15th seconds from both right and left side.

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code? post here.

Comment: No sir i do not have any code to show u. but pls if u have then pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

As you have given any specific details, i assume you are using RangeSeekBar
for maintaining constant distance between thumbs try using the difference
(progress value of leftThumb - progress value of rightThumb).

if the difference is equal to your desired value (15 in your example) then disable the seek bar.

checkhere 
[How to set range between two thumbs in range seek bar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131967/how-to-set-range-between-two-thumbs-in-range-seek-bar-in-android)

Second method you can use is:

get the current progress value of leftThumb and rightThumb

if the difference between them is '15' then set the progress of the rightThumb
as

seekTo (progress value of leftThumb + 15) under the if condition

(progress value of leftThumb - progress value of rightThumb) == 15

cant use exact and proper variables here add some more details.
hope it helps