# How to set range between two thumbs in range seek bar in android?

Tags: android, range, android-seekbar

I am using the range seek bar in my app.It's working fine but my requirement is set the range between the two thumbs.In default both thumbs are overlapping each other in my case thumbs are not overlapping each other.

How to set the range between the both thumbs in range seek bar?

below is my range seek bar class.In my case difference between the two thumbs is 3.if two thumbs difference is 3,thumbs are can't overlap.how to set range between the thumbs?

here is the class what i used

```
public class RangeSeekBar<T extends Number> extends ImageView {
    private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private final Bitmap thumbImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.seekcircle_blue);
    private final Bitmap thumbPressedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.seekcircle_red);
    private final float thumbWidth = thumbImage.getWidth();
    private final float thumbHalfWidth = 0.5f * thumbWidth;
    private final float thumbHalfHeight = 0.5f * thumbImage.getHeight();
    private final float lineHeight = 0.8f * thumbHalfHeight;
    private final float padding = thumbHalfWidth;
    private final T absoluteMinValue, absoluteMaxValue;
    private final NumberType numberType;
    private final double absoluteMinValuePrim, absoluteMaxValuePrim;
    private double normalizedMinValue = 0d;
    private double normalizedMaxValue = 1d;
    private Thumb pressedThumb = null;
    private boolean notifyWhileDragging = false;
    private OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<T> listener;

    /**
     * Default color of a {@link RangeSeekBar}, #FF33B5E5. This is also known as "Ice Cream Sandwich" blue.
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.argb(0xFF, 0, 0, 0);

    /**
     * An invalid pointer id.
     */
    public static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = 255;

    // Localized constants from MotionEvent for compatibility
    // with API < 8 "Froyo".
    public static final int ACTION_POINTER_UP = 0x6, ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK = 0x0000ff00, ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT = 8;

    private float mDownMotionX;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    /**
     * On touch, this offset plus the scaled value from the position of the touch will form the progress value. Usually 0.
     */
    float mTouchProgressOffset;

    private int mScaledTouchSlop;
    private boolean mIsDragging;

    /**
     * Creates a new RangeSeekBar.
     * 
     * @param absoluteMinValue
     *            The minimum value of the selectable range.
     * @param absoluteMaxValue
     *            The maximum value of the selectable range.
     * @param context
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             Will be thrown if min/max value type is not one of Long, Double, Integer, Float, Short, Byte or BigDecimal.
     */
    public RangeSeekBar(T absoluteMinValue, T absoluteMaxValue, Context context) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            super(context);
            this.absoluteMinValue = absoluteMinValue;
            this.absoluteMaxValue = absoluteMaxValue;
            absoluteMinValuePrim = absoluteMinValue.doubleValue();
            absoluteMaxValuePrim = absoluteMaxValue.doubleValue();
            numberType = NumberType.fromNumber(absoluteMinValue);

            // make RangeSeekBar focusable. This solves focus handling issues in case EditText widgets are being used along with the RangeSeekBar within ScollViews.
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            init();
    }

    private final void init() {
            mScaledTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    public boolean isNotifyWhileDragging() {
            return notifyWhileDragging;
    }

    /**
     * Should the widget notify the listener callback while the user is still dragging a thumb? Default is false.
     * 
     * @param flag
     */
    public void setNotifyWhileDragging(boolean flag) {
            this.notifyWhileDragging = flag;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the absolute minimum value of the range that has been set at construction time.
     * 
     * @return The absolute minimum value of the range.
     */
    public T getAbsoluteMinValue() {
            return absoluteMinValue;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the absolute maximum value of the range that has been set at construction time.
     * 
     * @return The absolute maximum value of the range.
     */
    public T getAbsoluteMaxValue() {
            return absoluteMaxValue;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the currently selected min value.
     * 
     * @return The currently selected min value.
     */
    public T getSelectedMinValue() {
            return normalizedToValue(normalizedMinValue);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the currently selected minimum value. The widget will be invalidated and redrawn.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The Number value to set the minimum value to. Will be clamped to given absolute minimum/maximum range.
     */
    public void setSelectedMinValue(T value) {
            // in case absoluteMinValue == absoluteMaxValue, avoid division by zero when normalizing.
            if (0 == (absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim)) {
                    setNormalizedMinValue(0d);
            }
            else {
                    setNormalizedMinValue(valueToNormalized(value));
            }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the currently selected max value.
     * 
     * @return The currently selected max value.
     */
    public T getSelectedMaxValue() {
            return normalizedToValue(normalizedMaxValue);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the currently selected maximum value. The widget will be invalidated and redrawn.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The Number value to set the maximum value to. Will be clamped to given absolute minimum/maximum range.
     */
    public void setSelectedMaxValue(T value) {
            // in case absoluteMinValue == absoluteMaxValue, avoid division by zero when normalizing.
            if (0 == (absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim)) {
                    setNormalizedMaxValue(1d);
            }
            else {
                    setNormalizedMaxValue(valueToNormalized(value));
            }
    }

    /**
     * Registers given listener callback to notify about changed selected values.
     * 
     * @param listener
     *            The listener to notify about changed selected values.
     */
    public void setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<T> listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Handles thumb selection and movement. Notifies listener callback on certain events.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            if (!isEnabled())
                    return false;

            int pointerIndex;

            final int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Remember where the motion event started
                    mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(event.getPointerCount() - 1);
                    pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    mDownMotionX = event.getX(pointerIndex);

                    pressedThumb = evalPressedThumb(mDownMotionX);

                    // Only handle thumb presses.
                    if (pressedThumb == null)
                            return super.onTouchEvent(event);

                    setPressed(true);
                    invalidate();
                    onStartTrackingTouch();
                    trackTouchEvent(event);
                    attemptClaimDrag();

                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (pressedThumb != null) {

                            if (mIsDragging) {
                                    trackTouchEvent(event);
                            }
                            else {
                                    // Scroll to follow the motion event
                                    pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                                    final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);

                                    if (Math.abs(x - mDownMotionX) > mScaledTouchSlop) {
                                            setPressed(true);
                                            invalidate();
                                            onStartTrackingTouch();
                                            trackTouchEvent(event);
                                            attemptClaimDrag();
                                    }
                            }

                            if (listener != null) {
                                    listener.onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(this, getSelectedMinValue(), getSelectedMaxValue());
                            }
                    }
                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (mIsDragging) {
                            trackTouchEvent(event);
                            onStopTrackingTouch();
                            setPressed(false);
                    }
                    else {
                            // Touch up when we never crossed the touch slop threshold
                            // should be interpreted as a tap-seek to that location.
                            onStartTrackingTouch();
                            trackTouchEvent(event);
                            onStopTrackingTouch();
                    }

                    pressedThumb = null;
                    invalidate();
                    if (listener != null) {
                            listener.onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(this, getSelectedMinValue(), getSelectedMaxValue());
                    }
                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                    final int index = event.getPointerCount() - 1;
                    // final int index = ev.getActionIndex();
                    mDownMotionX = event.getX(index);
                    mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(index);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    onSecondaryPointerUp(event);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    if (mIsDragging) {
                            onStopTrackingTouch();
                            setPressed(false);
                    }
                    invalidate(); // see above explanation
                    break;
            }
            return true;
    }

    private final void onSecondaryPointerUp(MotionEvent ev) {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;

            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose
                    // a new active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    // TODO: Make this decision more intelligent.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mDownMotionX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
    }

    private final void trackTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            final int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);

            if (Thumb.MIN.equals(pressedThumb)) {
                    setNormalizedMinValue(screenToNormalized(x));
            }
            else if (Thumb.MAX.equals(pressedThumb)) {
                    setNormalizedMaxValue(screenToNormalized(x));
            }
    }

    /**
     * Tries to claim the user's drag motion, and requests disallowing any ancestors from stealing events in the drag.
     */
    private void attemptClaimDrag() {
            if (getParent() != null) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the user has started touching this widget.
     */
    void onStartTrackingTouch() {
            mIsDragging = true;
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the user either releases his touch or the touch is canceled.
     */
    void onStopTrackingTouch() {
            mIsDragging = false;
    }

    /**
     * Ensures correct size of the widget.
     */
    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int width = 200;
            if (MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED != MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec)) {
                    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            }
            int height = thumbImage.getHeight();
            if (MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED != MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec)) {
                    height = Math.min(height, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
            }
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    /**
     * Draws the widget on the given canvas.
     */
    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            // draw seek bar background line
            final RectF rect = new RectF(padding, 0.5f * (getHeight() - lineHeight), getWidth() - padding, 0.5f * (getHeight() + lineHeight));
            paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

            // draw seek bar active range line
            rect.left = normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue);
            rect.right = normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue);

            // orange color
            paint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

            // draw minimum thumb
            drawThumb(normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue), Thumb.MIN.equals(pressedThumb), canvas);

            // draw maximum thumb

            drawThumb_max(normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue), Thumb.MAX.equals(pressedThumb), canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to save instance state when device orientation changes. This method is called automatically if you assign an id to the RangeSeekBar widget using the {@link #setId(int)} method. Other members of this class than the normalized min and max values don't need to be saved.
     */
    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("SUPER", super.onSaveInstanceState());
            bundle.putDouble("MIN", normalizedMinValue);
            bundle.putDouble("MAX", normalizedMaxValue);
            return bundle;
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to restore instance state when device orientation changes. This method is called automatically if you assign an id to the RangeSeekBar widget using the {@link #setId(int)} method.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable parcel) {
            final Bundle bundle = (Bundle) parcel;
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable("SUPER"));
            normalizedMinValue = bundle.getDouble("MIN");
            normalizedMaxValue = bundle.getDouble("MAX");
    }

    /**
     * Draws the "normal" resp. "pressed" thumb image on specified x-coordinate.
     * 
     * @param screenCoord
     *            The x-coordinate in screen space where to draw the image.
     * @param pressed
     *            Is the thumb currently in "pressed" state?
     * @param canvas
     *            The canvas to draw upon.
     */
    private void drawThumb(float screenCoord, boolean pressed, Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(pressed ? thumbImage : thumbImage, screenCoord - thumbHalfWidth, (float) ((0.5f * getHeight()) - thumbHalfHeight), paint);
    }

    private void drawThumb_max(float screenCoord, boolean pressed, Canvas canvas)
    {
            canvas.drawBitmap(pressed ? thumbPressedImage : thumbPressedImage, screenCoord - thumbHalfWidth, (float) ((0.5f * getHeight()) - thumbHalfHeight), paint);
    }

    /**
     * Decides which (if any) thumb is touched by the given x-coordinate.
     * 
     * @param touchX
     *            The x-coordinate of a touch event in screen space.
     * @return The pressed thumb or null if none has been touched.
     */
    private Thumb evalPressedThumb(float touchX) {
            Thumb result = null;
            boolean minThumbPressed = isInThumbRange(touchX, normalizedMinValue);
            boolean maxThumbPressed = isInThumbRange(touchX, normalizedMaxValue);
            if (minThumbPressed && maxThumbPressed) {
                    // if both thumbs are pressed (they lie on top of each other), choose the one with more room to drag. this avoids "stalling" the thumbs in a corner, not being able to drag them apart anymore.
                    result = (touchX / getWidth() > 0.5f) ? Thumb.MIN : Thumb.MAX;
            }
            else if (minThumbPressed) {
                    result = Thumb.MIN;
            }
            else if (maxThumbPressed) {
                    result = Thumb.MAX;
            }
            return result;
    }

    /**
     * Decides if given x-coordinate in screen space needs to be interpreted as "within" the normalized thumb x-coordinate.
     * 
     * @param touchX
     *            The x-coordinate in screen space to check.
     * @param normalizedThumbValue
     *            The normalized x-coordinate of the thumb to check.
     * @return true if x-coordinate is in thumb range, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isInThumbRange(float touchX, double normalizedThumbValue) {
            return Math.abs(touchX - normalizedToScreen(normalizedThumbValue)) <= thumbHalfWidth;
    }

    /**
     * Sets normalized min value to value so that 0 <= value <= normalized max value <= 1. The View will get invalidated when calling this method.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The new normalized min value to set.
     */
    public void setNormalizedMinValue(double value) {
            normalizedMinValue = Math.max(0d, Math.min(1d, Math.min(value, normalizedMaxValue)));
            invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets normalized max value to value so that 0 <= normalized min value <= value <= 1. The View will get invalidated when calling this method.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The new normalized max value to set.
     */
    public void setNormalizedMaxValue(double value) {
            normalizedMaxValue = Math.max(0d, Math.min(1d, Math.max(value, normalizedMinValue)));
            invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Converts a normalized value to a Number object in the value space between absolute minimum and maximum.
     * 
     * @param normalized
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private T normalizedToValue(double normalized) {
            return (T) numberType.toNumber(absoluteMinValuePrim + normalized * (absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim));
    }

    /**
     * Converts the given Number value to a normalized double.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The Number value to normalize.
     * @return The normalized double.
     */
    private double valueToNormalized(T value) {
            if (0 == absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim) {
                    // prevent division by zero, simply return 0.
                    return 0d;
            }
            return (value.doubleValue() - absoluteMinValuePrim) / (absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a normalized value into screen space.
     * 
     * @param normalizedCoord
     *            The normalized value to convert.
     * @return The converted value in screen space.
     */
    private float normalizedToScreen(double normalizedCoord) {
            return (float) (padding + normalizedCoord * (getWidth() - 2 * padding));
    }

    /**
     * Converts screen space x-coordinates into normalized values.
     * 
     * @param screenCoord
     *            The x-coordinate in screen space to convert.
     * @return The normalized value.
     */
    private double screenToNormalized(float screenCoord) {
            int width = getWidth();
            if (width <= 2 * padding) {
                    // prevent division by zero, simply return 0.
                    return 0d;
            }
            else {
                    double result = (screenCoord - padding) / (width - 2 * padding);
                    return Math.min(1d, Math.max(0d, result));
            }
    }

    /**
     * Callback listener interface to notify about changed range values.
     * 
     * @author Stephan Tittel (stephan.tittel@kom.tu-darmstadt.de)
     * 
     * @param <T>
     *            The Number type the RangeSeekBar has been declared with.
     */
    public interface OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<T> {
            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, T minValue, T maxValue);
    }

    /**
     * Thumb constants (min and max).
     */
    private static enum Thumb {
            MIN, MAX
    };

    /**
     * Utility enumaration used to convert between Numbers and doubles.
     * 
     * @author Stephan Tittel (stephan.tittel@kom.tu-darmstadt.de)
     * 
     */
    private static enum NumberType {
            LONG, DOUBLE, INTEGER, FLOAT, SHORT, BYTE, BIG_DECIMAL;

            public static <E extends Number> NumberType fromNumber(E value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                    if (value instanceof Long) {
                            return LONG;
                    }
                    if (value instanceof Double) {
                            return DOUBLE;
                    }
                    if (value instanceof Integer) {
                            return INTEGER;
                    }
                    if (value instanceof Float) {
                            return FLOAT;
                    }
                    if (value instanceof Short) {
                            return SHORT;
                    }
                    if (value instanceof Byte) {
                            return BYTE;
                    }
                    if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
                            return BIG_DECIMAL;
                    }
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number class '" + value.getClass().getName() + "' is not supported");
            }

            public Number toNumber(double value) {
                    switch (this) {
                    case LONG:
                            return new Long((long) value);
                    case DOUBLE:
                            return value;
                    case INTEGER:
                            return new Integer((int) value);
                    case FLOAT:
                            return new Float(value);
                    case SHORT:
                            return new Short((short) value);
                    case BYTE:
                            return new Byte((byte) value);
                    case BIG_DECIMAL:
                            return new BigDecimal(value);
                    }
                    throw new InstantiationError("can't convert " + this + " to a Number object");
            }
    }}
```

[image]

EDIT:Java Class Code

```
// create RangeSeekBar as Integer range between 20 and 75
    final RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(0, 35, this);
    seekBar.setSelectedMinValue(5);
   seekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(8);
    seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
                    // handle changed range values
                    Log.i(TAG, "User selected new range values: MIN=" + minValue + ", MAX=" + maxValue);



                int diff=maxValue-minValue;
                if(diff==4)
                {




                }



            }
    });

    // add RangeSeekBar to pre-defined layout
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.addView(seekBar);
```

Comment: can you please show your java class, where you used the RangeSeekBar.

Comment: tell the range value b/w your thumbs in your RangeSeekBar. Which is set in this method.
seekBar.setRangeValues(0, 100);

Comment: @AmanGupta Thanks for reply,i tried this but no use.In my case both slider are not moved together when reach the difference is 4.

Comment: your means when the sliders difference is 4 then they are not moving.

have you used this method **seekBar.setNotifyWhileDragging(true);**
for notify the range values of both the thumbs while dragging.

Comment: Edit your answer and add the java code where you have used RangeSeekBar.

Comment: @AmanGupta,Please see my edited code

Comment: ok means you want when the difference is 4 then thumbs should not be moved. am I write or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stopping the motion of thumbs when the difference is 4. You can use

```
if(diff==4) {
    bar.setEnabled(false);
}
```

For getting more clear go to our [blog](http://mobikul.com/how-to-make-range-seekbar-or-dual-thumbs-seekbar-in-android/) and see **How to disable thumbs while dragging in RangedSeekBar** section.

Comment: Your welcome @Rajesh. May you please comment on our blog.
 http://mobikul.com/how-to-make-range-seekbar-or-dual-thumbs-seekbar-in-android/

Comment: @AmanGupta hi can u help me i m failed to show range values between two times that is in milliseconfs

Comment: @Erum may be this SO link will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243318/android-time-range-seek-bar

And if not, please share your java code then I can help you.