# Android Time Range Seek Bar

Tags: android, video, time, range, seekbar

I want to allow the user of my app to trim a specific part from a video. And i'm looking for a solution that can help me make a time selection slider with two thumbs(Max and Min time).

This is a sample of what i want to achieve .

[image]

I know that there is already some librarys that can help:

[android-range-seek-bar](https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar)

[Material Range Bar](https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar)

But they work only with floats and integers.
My question is how can i make it work with time values ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can represent time with a numeric type! With integer you can have a range time from `0` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` seconds (for example)

What do you need is display this int value in a `mm:ss` format.

I don't know if the libs up here already do this, however I suggest to fork one on that and work on the values displayed on screen.

Example from another (using millis) [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format)

```
String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
```

Comment: I think that is the only way to do it. However we will wait if someone else have another solution