# Double thumb Seek Bar like Paytm

Tags: android, seekbar

I have SeekBar, I used https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar for built SeekBar it's working good but it's interact with each other on drag but i don't want to it, I want to like paytm. and when I set enlarged value to start tick and end tick means max and min value, then tick not showing the whole value that means half value is showing.

So how can i build it? Please help me!!!

activity_main.xml

```
<com.example.seekbar.RangeBar xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/rangebar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                custom:temporaryPins="false"
                custom:tickEnd="100"
                custom:tickInterval="10"
                custom:tickStart="0" />
```

Comment: Please try to reword your question, it is really hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131967/how-to-set-range-between-two-thumbs-in-range-seek-bar-in-android this type of functionality in my RangeSeekBar